# Concatenate values from different columns with Data Import Handler

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler

I have a Django application which connects to a Solr instance for searching. How can I put the firstname and the surname in the same tune_author Solr field (see below)?

```
    <entity name="tune" query="select id,type,name,start_page,alternate_spellings,item_id from bassculture_tune">
      <field column="id" name="id"/>
      <field column="type" name="type"/>
      <field column="name" name="name"/>
      <entity name="tune_author" query="select id,firstname,surname from bassculture_author where id=${tune.item_id.source_id.author_id}">

        </entity>
```

Right now I get the firstname and surname as separate fields in my results, and tune_author is empty. How can I get a tune_author Solr field filled with firstname + surname?

EDIT

OK, I think there's also a more basic issue with my understanding of SQL querying.

My situation is:

```
author_table:
id, firstname, surname ...
    
source_table:
id, source_title, author_id ... 

copy_table:
id, copy_title, source_id ...

tune_table:
id, tune_title, copy_id ...
```

So, I want the author's full name of a tune. A tune belongs to a copy. A copy belongs to a source. A source, finally, has the author's ID (and the author_table has the author's details from which I want to reconstruct the full name). I hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it directly in SQL:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname) AS tune_author FROM ...
```

It'll give you the concatenated entry directly in your SQL row. I don't think you'll need a field entry in that case, but if necessary:

```
<field column="tune_author" name="tune_author"/>
```

You can also use a TemplateTransformer on your entity to use a string template:

```
<entity name="tune_author" query="..." transformer="TemplateTransformer">
    <field column="tune_author" template="${tune_author.firstname} ${tune_author.surname}" />
</entity>
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising, especially the TemplateTransformer. Now, is something like select id,firstname,surname,extrainfo from bassculture_author where id=${tune.item.source.author_id} OK? As you can guess, I'm trying to get the author_id which is in the source table, in which the source is linked to the copy. My tune_author field is empty now, which make me think I'm not traversing the tables properly.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your exact layout (your `item_id.source_id.author_id` key seems wrong), but you can probably solve it by having a join if there is only one matching row anyway - that way you only have the parent entity. Something like `SELECT bt.*, CONCAT(ta.firstname, ' ', ta.surname) AS tune_author FROM  bassculture_tune bt, bassculture_author ba WHERE bt.author_id = ba.id`

Comment: I've updated my question to include more details about my database structure; what you suggest is not working for me as it is. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to join all the way through in that case; `SELECT bt.*, CONCAT(ta.firstname, ' ', ta.surname) AS tune_author FROM bassculture_tune bt, copy_table c, source_table s, bassculture_author ba WHERE bt.copy_id = c.id AND c.source_id = s.id AND s.author_id = ba.id` - and always debug these queries by running them directly in the DB, not through DIH. This assumes that each id only points to one row (which seems logical) and that all rows have ids (otherwise, `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go)

Comment: I'm afraid this is still not doing what I want (although at least now I _am_ getting something!). This outputs 1349 records (i.e. all the tunes) of tune_author with id=1. In other words, all the tunes appear written by the author with id 1, which is not true.

Comment: Wait, I might have done it with a little edit t o your code - stay tuned.